# Data is inserted automatically

Tags: php, wordpress

In this code everything is working fine it take user name from session and insert data perfectly via radio button, only problem is it automatically insert data again when I reload the page.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&&isset($_POST['r1'])&&isset($_POST['r2'])&&isset($_POST['r3'])&&isset($_POST['r4'])&&isset($_POST['suggestion'])&&isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user=$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $r1=$_POST['r1'];
    $r2=$_POST['r2'];
    $r3=$_POST['r3'];
    $r4=$_POST['r4'];
    $suggestion=$_POST['suggestion'];
    $query_insert="INSERT INTO `wp_feedback` VALUES ('".$user."','".$r1."','".$r2."','".$r3."','".$r4."','".$suggestion."')";

    if($query_run=mysql_query($query_insert)){
    echo "alright";
    }
    else {
        echo "not inserted";
        }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you reload your page after insert, browser repeats POST request. To avoid this behaviour you should redirect user to a view page after inserting to database.

Comment: redirect when 1st inserted

Comment: As a (rather important) side note, please read up on [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Incorrectly_filtered_escape_characters).

Comment: Yes it worked, but one more question ,here is a sample code  `mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('try');

if(isset($_POST['r1'])&&isset($_POST['submit'])){
$select=$_POST['r1'];

$query="INSERT INTO `tyr`VALUES ('".$select."')";

if($query_run=mysql_query($query)){
 echo "inserted";
 }
 else {
  echo "not inserted";
  }`  In this code it does not insert again on reload .So what is wrong or right with this sample code that I used for trial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it,

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&&isset($_POST['r1'])&&isset($_POST['r2'])&&isset($_POST['r3'])&&isset($_POST['r4'])&&isset($_POST['suggestion'])&&isset($_POST['submit']))
{
         $user=$_SESSION['user_id']; 
         $r1=$_POST['r1']; 
         $r2=$_POST['r2']; 
         $r3=$_POST['r3']; 
         $r4=$_POST['r4']; 
         $suggestion=$_POST['suggestion']; 
         $query_insert="INSERT INTO wp_feedback VALUES ('".$user."','".$r1."','".$r2."','".$r3."','".$r4."','".$suggestion."')";


    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        if($query_run=mysql_query($query_insert))
        {
            echo "alright";
            header('Location:setlocation.php');
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "not inserted";
        }
    }
}
```

set header location after insert query...

Answer (score 1):

Put a redirection at the buttom of your script because i think reloading the page still
execute your form submission

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&&isset($_POST['r1'])&&isset($_POST['r2'])&&isset($_POST['r3'])&&isset($_POST['r4'])&&isset($_POST['suggestion'])&&isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user=$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $r1=$_POST['r1'];
    $r2=$_POST['r2'];
    $r3=$_POST['r3'];
    $r4=$_POST['r4'];
    $suggestion=$_POST['suggestion'];
    $query_insert="INSERT INTO `wp_feedback` VALUES ('".$user."','".$r1."','".$r2."','".$r3."','".$r4."','".$suggestion."')";

    if($query_run=mysql_query($query_insert)){
    echo "alright";
    }
    else {
        echo "not inserted";
        }
header('Location: redirect url');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&&isset($_POST['r1'])&&isset($_POST['r2'])&&isset($_POST['r3'])&&isset($_POST['r4'])&&isset($_POST['suggestion'])&&isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user=$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $r1=$_POST['r1'];
    $r2=$_POST['r2'];
    $r3=$_POST['r3'];
    $r4=$_POST['r4'];
    $suggestion=$_POST['suggestion'];
    $query_insert="INSERT INTO `wp_feedback` VALUES ('".$user."','".$r1."','".$r2."','".$r3."','".$r4."','".$suggestion."')";

    if($query_run=mysql_query($query_insert)){
    echo "alright";
    header("Location:someurl");//This will redirect into some other pages and solve your problem
    }
    else {
        echo "not inserted";
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&&isset($_POST['r1'])&&isset($_POST['r2'])&&isset($_POST['r3'])&&isset($_POST['r4'])&&isset($_POST['suggestion'])&&isset($_POST['submit'])){
$user=$_SESSION['user_id'];
$r1=$_POST['r1'];
$r2=$_POST['r2'];
$r3=$_POST['r3'];
$r4=$_POST['r4'];
$suggestion=$_POST['suggestion'];
$query_insert="INSERT INTO `wp_feedback` VALUES ('".$user."','".$r1."','".$r2."','".$r3."','".$r4."','".$suggestion."')";

if($query_run=mysql_query($query_insert)){
echo "alright";
}
else {
    echo "not inserted";
    }
 header('Location:yourpage.php');
```

}